# How to normalize this data

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is a minimum data to reproduce the question:

```
@prefix rs: <http://example.org/rs#>
@prefix bo: <http://example.org/bo#>
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

rs:user1 rs:hasRated [rs:by "1.0"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:animalFarm] .

rs:user2 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.9"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:animalFarm] .

rs:user3 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.9"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:animalFarm] .

rs:user4 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.5"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:book3] .

rs:user5 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.6"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:book3] .

rs:user6 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.8"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:algorithem1] .

rs:user7 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.9"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:algorithem1] .

rs:user8 rs:hasRated [rs:by "0.3"^^xsd:float ; rs:item bo:book4] .
```

I want to normalize the *average of rating for each item*, and also normalize the *number of ratings for each item*

I can take the *average of ratings for each item*, and the *number of ratings for each item* as the following:

```
PREFIX  bo:   <http://example.org/bo#>
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  rs:   <http://example.org/rs#>
select ?item (AVG(?ratingValue) as ?avg) (COUNT(*) as ?count) 
{
    ?user rs:hasRated [ rs:item ?item ;  rs:by ?ratingValue ] .
}
group by ?item
```

and the result is:

[image]

What I would like, if possible, is to have the following:

```
bo:book3                 (0.55/(0.55 + 0.93333334 + 0.85 + 0.3 ))   (2/(2 + 3 + 2 + 1))
```

and off course the same for the other items.

my problem is that I don't know how to make the *sum*, and at the same time do the division.

Your help is highly appreciated .

#### Update 1

I am asking about the possibility to do that, if not (or if performance is too bad) i got with different solution

Comment: You can use a Sub-SELECT which is basically your current query and apply aggregation on its result in the outer query.

Comment: @AKSW could you rephrase your comment in an answer that has a query? I highly doubt that a sub query would work because how are you going to have the division on the sum? you can have the sum (yes) but how are you going to do (0.55/sumValue) ?

Comment: @AniaDavid I've added an answer.  It helps to try some of these things to see if they work, before asking a question on Stack Overflow, because what you mentioned in the comment is actually the answer.  You do: `select ?item (avg(?rating_)/?sumAvgRating as ?rating) (count(*)/?countRating as ?percentCount) ...`.

Answer (score 3):

In SPARQL, the data is either grouped or it isn't.  You can't really "reach out" from the group and get information that's bigger than the group.  That means that to get this, you'll probably need to have a subquery that gets the total values separately.  With the data that you've given:

```sql
select ?item
       (avg(?rating_)/?sumAvgRating as ?rating)
       (count(*)/?countRating as ?percentCount)
{
  ?user rs:hasRated [ rs:by ?rating_ ; rs:item ?item ]

  #-- get number of ratings
  { select (count(*) as ?countRating) { ?user rs:hasRated [] }}

  #-- get sum of average ratings
  { select (sum(?avgRating) as ?sumAvgRating) {
      { select (avg(?rating_) as ?avgRating) {
          ?user rs:hasRated [ rs:by ?rating_ ; rs:item ?item ]
        }
        group by ?item
      }
    }
  }
}
group by ?item ?countRating ?sumAvgRating
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| item           | rating                  | percentCount |
===========================================================
| bo:book3       | "0.20886075"^^xsd:float | 0.25         |
| bo:book4       | "0.11392405"^^xsd:float | 0.125        |
| bo:algorithem1 | "0.3227848"^^xsd:float  | 0.25         |
| bo:animalFarm  | "0.35443038"^^xsd:float | 0.375        |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I think that to get the data you really want, and to do it without redundant subqueries, you'll need some post-processing on the results. I say that because you're really asking for some computation that involves grouping in two different ways.  To get the total number of ratings, you need a group over all the results (or at least over a group over some grouped results).  To get the averages for each item, you need to group over the items.  To get the sum of the averages, you need to group over the grouped data.  So I don't think that you can do this perfectly without some redundant querying.

But, you can *some* of the processing within the query.  I think that I'd get the items and their ratings, and the count the ratings and **sum** the averages for each item, like this:

```sql
select ?item (sum(?rating_) as ?sumRating) (count(*) as ?countRating) {
  ?user rs:hasRated [ rs:by ?rating_ ; rs:item ?item ]
}
group by ?item
```

The reason I do this, rather than *averaging* the ratings, is that from the count and the sum you can easily reconstruct the average (just divide the sum by the count), and you can get the sum of the sums, and the sum of the counts.  If you do the average too early, then you can't determine what the sum of all the ratings actually was.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the thing is that you are repeating the same query three times, and in my real ontology (real data), i per say will need to repeat the same query three times to make your query.

Comment: @AniaDavid Yes, that will make the problem more difficult.  It may make more sense to obtain the raw data and then post-process in the application.  Doing it all in the query is difficult.  There may be some options to avoid the repetition here, though.  For instance, when you're computing the average rating for each item, you can also compute the number of ratings for the item, and then the sum of those is the total number of ratings.  Actually, that gives me an idea...

Comment: one more thing is that let's add an having on the query that calculates the *sum of average rating*, that should reduce the number of rows in the results, but acutally because of the count, you will still get all the items in the rseults . you got me please? try to add this ` having (?avgRating >= 441)` you will still get all the items though none of them have the avgRating bigger than 441 obviously

Comment: @AniaDavid I updated my answer with a bit.  The real issue is that you need: (i) some data that (conceptually) requires a single group (the total number of ratings); (ii) some data that is grouped by item (average rating for each item); and (iii) some data that is grouped over a grouping (sum of average ratings).  To get those different kinds of groups, you'll need either (a) multiple subqueries, or (b) post-processing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be checking later tomorrow, now I've to do another "new" thing, and I'll ask a quesiton about it